# Заполнить сечения python turtle

Tags: python, turtle

Как можно залить фигуру которая образовалась в результате сечения? Вот как получилось у меня:
[image: Вот как получилось у меня]

А вот как нужно :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
#Рисуем круги
t.circle(80)#80 радиус
t.left(90)#80 градусов
t.forward(40)#40 шагов
t.right(90)
t.circle(40)

#Рисуем крест
t.right(90)
t.forward(120)
t.right(180)
t.forward(320)
t.right(180)
t.forward(160)
t.right(90)
t.forward(160)
t.right(180)
t.forward(320)
t.right(180)
t.forward(160)
t.right(90)

#Рисуем фигуры
t.right(45) #Кут 45 градусов
t.forward(180)
t.right(180)
t.forward(180)
t.right(45)
t.left(90)
t.left(60) #Кут 45 градусов
t.forward(180)
```

Хотел залить их с помощью функций turtle.begin_fill(), но что-то не получилось(не фортануло)

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Приведите весь код и с импортами и с тем куском, где не получилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужно прорисовывать тот участок, который  хочешь закрасить отдельно. В начале команд ставить t.begin_fill(), после последней t.end_fill(). Вот пример.

```
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(80, 45)#80 радиус
t.left(90)
t.forward(80)
t.left(135)
t.forward(80)
t.end_fill()
t.getscreen()._root.mainloop()
```